# PHP change link address in html source code

Tags: php, html, replace

In source code I have address's like this `/images/image.jpg` `js/file.js` how to add to this address's server address that will be  `http://server.com/folder/file.jpg` with `str_replace()` it will be hard, because each folder name is different.

Comment: Probably easier to use IDE/text editor and search and replace.

Comment: please rate & accept the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using preg:

```
$content = '
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>
  blah blah <a href="/images/image1.jpg">image1</a>
  blah blah <a href="/images/image2.jpg">image2</a>
  blah blah <a href="/folder/link1.htm">link1
';

$search = array('#"(/)images/#mi', '#"(/)folder/#mi', '#\"(/)js/#mi');
$replace = "http://site.com$1";

$content = preg_replace($search, $replace, $content);
```

Comment: this is only applicable when the entire content is generated in the controller, which is not a good MVC framework practice.

Answer (score 0):

declare a global variable for your server address, store all your folder names into an array, and traverse it with a loop, and then concatenate the strings. Example: see it in action [here](http://codepad.org/GbXLMW1l)

```
  $server_addr = "http://server.com";   
  //considering $replace and $folder_names have 1:1 correspondence of search and replace values 
 $orig = array("/images/image.jpg", "js/file.js"); //and so on...
 $replace = array("images", "js"); //and so on...
 $folder_names = array('folder'); //and so on...

 for( $i=0; $i<=count($replace); $i++) {
  foreach ($orig as $o)
   $new_path[] = $server_addr . str_replace($replace[$i], $folder_names[$i], $o);
}
```

Comment: At which point `preg_replace` is probably better than `str_replace`.

Comment: preg_replace is used to replace regular expressions, whereas str_replace is for strings. so in this case, a str_replace is the way to go inside the loop.

Comment: or write good regex and loop less?  And why the looping anyway?  Both functions accept an array for needle and haystack.

Comment: you need a loop coz there are multiple phrases that need to be searched in.

Comment: "If search and replace are arrays, then str_replace() takes a value from each array and uses them to search and replace on subject. If replace has fewer values than search, then an empty string is used for the rest of replacement values. If search is an array and replace is a string, then this replacement string is used for every value of search. The converse would not make sense, though. "

Comment: first of all, i mentioned, if you consider an 1:1 correspondence between search & replace arrays. And also considering that, you would want to make that change across all the subject values.